# Show beginning of input field for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-inputmask

i have a question.
When i entered to input field very long text. Caret moves to the right. When focusout event happenes. It start to show text from the beginning. See screenshots for example:
http://prntscr.com/fr6vb0

http://prntscr.com/fr6vr4

In IE11 it doesn't move to the beginning.
http://prntscr.com/fr6wcn

I want to find some workaround how start to show this text in inputfield from 
the beginning in this case.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Perhaps try `this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 0;` in the `blur` event? Should set the cursor position to the beginning, but whether that will actually scroll the content at all I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
var input = $('.someInput');
input.focus().val(input.val());
input.blur().focus().val(input.val());
```